# Click event not being called for HTML submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need to add button in user control. When the button is clicked url should be captured and stored in a session. When I click the button, server click event is not being called. I am in confusion why it is not being called. Did I made anything wrong here? Please suggest.

I have the following code:

ascx:

```html
 <input type="submit" id="QuickViewbutton" value="Click to add this page to Quick View"
            runat="server" onserverclick="addQuickView" clientidmode="Static"/>
```

ascx.cs:

In page load:

```c#
 QuickViewbutton.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.addQuickView);
```

In protected void addQuickView(Object sender, EventArgs e) function I have written the code for fetching url:

```c#
string strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
Session["QuickViewUrl"] = strUrl;
```

Comment: Why do you add the event handler for the `ServerClick` event both declaratively (.ascx) and programmatically (in the page load)? I think  defining at one place is sufficient.

Comment: btw, @Dennis R is right, you do not need to declare event handler in code behind again. btw, is it giving any error?